# issue while running test @types/testing-library__react/node_modules/pretty-format/build/index.d.ts (7, 13): &#39;=&#39; expected

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

**@types/testing-library__react/node_modules/pretty-format/build/index.d.ts (7, 13): '=' expected.
getting this issue while running test, application is running fine.**

version and library used

"@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "testcafe": "^0.23.3",
  "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",

Comment: Can you attach a sample project with this problem?  Also, in the meantime, try updating to the latest TestCafe version.

Comment: @Alex Skorkin: how did you fix this issue? I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Typescript to > 3.8.0 solved this.

Comment: Upgrade where? In package.json? It does not work for me as I have `"typescript": "^4.0.3"`.
When I run gulp serve, I see the following  `[tsc] typescript version: 3.3.4000`